# Deleting builder-model-0.11.0.jar does not resolve error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I recently upgraded from Android studio 0.6.0 to 0.8.0 Beta. I get this error when I try to run the project onto a device:

> NoSuchMethodError: com.android.builder.model.AndroidArtifact.getOutputs()Ljava/util/Collection.

I Googled and followed [this link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72582) that advised that a file called builder-model-0.11.0.jar needed to be deleted. I did, but it doesn't seem to help. The error persists. Any help?

Comment: have you restarted your android studio after deleting said file?

Comment: this may be a silly mistake but there may be more people like me - ensure that you are deleting the file from the right location. Path to this folder in my system was /usr/share/android-studio/data/plugins/android/lib - Hope that helps

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Both of the answers are correct. Either do a clean install of the new SDK or delete the `builder-model-0.11.0.jar`.

The issue is that it was causing a conflict on what version of the `builder-model-x.x.x.jar`to use.

Note: There are also other duplicates (ex. `freemaker*.jar`), so doing a clean install rather than deleting would be the most ideal option and the way to go since this is the start of the new AS Beta.

Answer (score 12):

Delete builder-model-0.11.0.jar from plugins/android/lib﻿

Advice from here:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72582

- although I think they're fixing it for future releases:
  https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/99790/

Answer (score 5):

I was experiencing the same issue. I also upgraded from 0.6.0 by simply copying the android studio files to the application program folder. I found that uninstalling Android Studio, downloading the .exe installer from developer.android.com and re-installing Android Studio resolved the issue for me. I hope this works for you and others.